# How can I use @RabbitListener in multiple classes?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, message-queue, spring-amqp

I have a Spring application using RabbitMQ (spring-boot-starter-amqp).

I wanted to know if it's possible to use the `@RabbitListener` annotation across different classes.

I currently have two classes: `Receiver` and `DeadLetterQueue`

`Receiver.java`:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class Receiver {

  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

  @RabbitListener(queues = "queueName")
  public void receiveMessage(String message) throws Exception {
    logger.info("Received <{}>" + message.toString());

    throw new Exception("Error with the message");
  }
```

`DeadLetterQueue.java`:

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class DeadLetterQueue {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @RabbitListener(queues = "otherQueueName")
    public void processFailedMessages(String message) {
        logger.info("Received failed message<{}>:" + message.toString());
    }
}
```

`RabbitMqConfig.java`:

```
@Data
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "rabbitmq")
public class RabbitMqConfig {

  private String host;
  private int port;
  private String username;
  private String password;
  private String queue;
  private String exchange;
  private String dlq;
  private String dlx;
  private String routingKey;

  @Bean
  Queue incomingQueue() {
    return QueueBuilder.durable(queue)
            .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", dlx)
            .build();
  }

  @Bean
  FanoutExchange deadLetterExchange() {
    return new FanoutExchange(dlx);
  }

  @Bean
  Queue deadLetterQueue() {
    return QueueBuilder.durable(dlq).build();
  }

  @Bean
  Binding deadLetterBinding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(deadLetterQueue()).to(deadLetterExchange());
  }

  @Bean
  DirectExchange incomingQueueExchange() {
    return new DirectExchange(exchange);
  }

  @Bean
  Binding incomingQueueBinding() {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(incomingQueue()).to(incomingQueueExchange()).with(queue);
  }
```

When I use the RabbitMQ management tool to post a message to the FanoutExchange, the `processFailedMessages` inside the `DeadLetterQueue` class doesn't log anything to the console. However if this method is inside of the `Receiver` class, everything works fine. Which led me to the assumption that `@RabbitListener` couldn't work across multiple classes unless there is some configuration which I am missing.

Other information:

- I'm using Docker to run the RabbitMQ Server
- Strangely, if I put the `receiveMessage()` method inside the `DeadLetterQueue` class, the expectations fail.

So: Is it possible to define queues in multiple classes with `@RabbitListener?`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have as many `@RabbitListener`s as you want, either in the same class or in multiple classes, as long as those classes are used in Spring beans.

Since you have `@Component` on both, it should work just fine, unless the `DeadLetterQueue` is in a package that is not scanned by Spring Boot.

Boot only looks at the packages and subpackages where the main `@SpringBootApplication` is located.

You can enable `DEBUG` logging for `org.springframework` to log all the bean creation during application initialization.

> I'm using Docker to run the RabbitMQ Server

The location of the broker is irrelevant.